# In Rails, how to pick an element from an array that is part of a params hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

An element from my params hash is an array by itself, like:

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"scan"=>{"scores"=>"66 73 75 47"},
 "commit"=>"report",
 "id"=>"6"}
```

I've searched and I've tried, but I can't find the right `params[....]` syntax to access the integers in the "scores"-array. I want to use them in my controller. )-: Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not an array, that's a space-separated list in a single string. Access it like this:

```
params[:scan][:scores].split.map(&:to_i)
```

(I'm assuming you want integers, not strings.)

Alternatively, if your code is making the request, you may be able to fix it to make the request with an array instead of a space-separated string.

Comment: Yes! That does the job. And it occurred strange to me that there were no comma's in the "array" = sp.sep.list. My code is supposed to pass the array-object as an hidden input value. Like:
`f.hidden_field :scores, value: @diskscores`
@diskscores is an array-object. I'll have to find something else there.

Comment: Using this code: 
`<% @diskscores.each do |ds| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :scores, :multiple => true, :value => ds %>
<% end %>` 
gave me an array "scores" directly in the params hash (instead of the space seperated string), so then there's no need for the `split.map` method. It didn't work to put the code in a block, because when I did that,  the input turned out not to be hidden, i.e. the score array was rendered to the view.